# android - close app if user not granting WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

in android 6 or above when user open app first time ask him for some permission
if he dont allow then exit app

some must required permission for my app is read and write to external storage, how to achieve this

i tried this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(LoginActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(LoginActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LoginActivity.this,
                            new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            1);
                } else {
                    //do something
                }
            } else {
                    //do something
            }
```

Comment: In `onRequestPermissionsResult()` method you can check your result. If permission is not granted then finis your activity.

Comment: how can i do this exactly? i am requesting permission on mainactivity when user enter, can you answer with some code

Comment: What enter ? From soft keyboard?

Comment: when user install app and open app / enter into app  ask some permission like some apps do and if user not allow then exit app, if user again open app then check permission granted or not if not again close app until he grant permissions what i want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using suggestion from @G. Brisida - Lince

i solved it and i am writing my answer here for other peoples if they need same thing,

this all code i write in MainActivity:

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
            {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                                                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                                                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                1);
    }
                else
                {
                    //do something
                }
            }
}
```

and this is override method onRequestPermissionsResult:

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch(requestCode)
        {
            case 1:
                if (grantResults.length > 0  && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                     // i am creating folder in external storage here
                 File create_dir=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/uca/");

                 Toast.makeText(this,"creating",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 create_dir.mkdirs();

                }
                else
                {
                    closeNow();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

this is close now mthod :

```
private void closeNow() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        {
            finishAffinity();
        }

        else
        {
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to read the results `onRequestPermissionsResult()` and if the user refused the permissions, call `context.finish()` or `context.finishAffinity()`.
Something like...
Edit: Take a look on the docs to learn how to handle the permissions: [Android 6 Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

```
    @Override 
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MAIN_PERMISSIONS:
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    // Validate the permissions result
                    if (permissionsOk) {
                        // All good
                    } else {
                        // Close your app
                        closeNow();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void closeNow() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            finishAffinity();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, i read docs over android 6 permission and it solved my question and i used your closeNow() with it

Answer (score 0):

Your application is close due to runtime exception not due to permission. Just open your logcat while running the application and check for exception or errors.

I hope it will work for you.